# SQL Date Range not including all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement:

```
select * from formsresponse fr, formsresponses frs
where fr.formsresponse_id = frs.formsresponse_id 
and fr.form_submitdate >= '3/13/2015' and fr.form_submitdate <= '3/31/2015'
```

The weird thing is that it's bring back a result set for records from 3/13 to 3/27 but the records with a date of 3/31 are not coming back.  They are in the database.  The field is a datetime field.  This makes no sense to me.  I have even tried the SQL with the BETWEEN statement and I get the same results.

Can anyone explain to me why this would be happening?

Comment: This is because your to date of `3/31/2015` is actually midnight on that date, so all records from that date are excluded.  You need to add a day to your to date to make this work.

Comment: Do you mean add a time?

Comment: I added the time to the date and it fixed it.

Comment: It would be better to add a day and change the condition to less than. That way you don't to worry about the exact time portion. Keep in mind that if the datatype changes to datetime2 the current max time is not the same max time available in datetime2.

Comment: That's also a great idea.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also convert the `fr.form_submitdate` field to date type without time to compare.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    formsresponse fr,
    formsresponses frs
WHERE
    fr.formsresponse_id = frs.formsresponse_id
    AND CAST(fr.form_submitdate AS DATE) BETWEEN '3/13/2015' AND '3/31/2015'
```

Assuming you might have an index on a datetime field for some reason and you need to change the end date in your procedure, you can just add 1 day to the end date.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    formsresponse fr,
    formsresponses frs
WHERE
    fr.formsresponse_id = frs.formsresponse_id
    AND fr.form_submitdate BETWEEN '3/13/2015' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '3/31/2015')
```

Comment: This is now nonSARGable and negates any indexes on form_submitdate. Also, you might take a look at this article about between. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: I've been doing sql long enough to know how between works.. I think I'll continue to use it where i see fit. I will keep the sargable thing in mind though

Comment: LOL you might know how it works but there are plenty of other out there that don't and may have to maintain your code. I am certainly not trying to tell you how to code or what expressions you should use. I offered that as a good piece of reading about a very commonly misunderstood and often incorrectly used expression.

Comment: heck, if i had a dime for every time I saw someone get `AND` and `OR` mixed up I'd have a few dollars.

Answer (score 3):

You have datetime that also has the time component in it, so it's not 00:00:00? Use smaller than operator:

```
select * from formsresponse fr, formsresponses frs
where fr.formsresponse_id = frs.formsresponse_id 
and fr.form_submitdate >= '20150313' and fr.form_submitdate < '20150401'
```

Also using YYYYMMDD is a lot safer option than the other formats